# Scipy curve_fit not fitting to gaussian

Tags: python, scipy

**I've generated a gaussian with the following code:**

```
x_array = np.linspace(0,0.5,100)
mu = 0.25  # Mean
sigma = 0.1  # Standard deviation
y_array_gauss = (1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x_array - mu) / sigma) ** 2)
y_array_gauss = y_array_gauss * (1.3 - 1.1) + 1.1

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time(s)': x_array, 'CH1(V)': y_array_gauss})
```

**Scipy function:**

```
def fit2(data, func, fit_init_guess, fit_bounds):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,6), facecolor='w')

    best_vals, covar = curve_fit(func, data['Time(s)'],data['CH1(V)'],p0 = fit_init_guess, bounds=fit_bounds)

    print(best_vals,'\n', covar)

    ax.plot(data['Time(s)'], data['CH1(V)'], '-')
    ax.plot(data['Time(s)'], func(data['Time(s)'], *best_vals),'r-',label='Fit:B+A*e^((-(delta_2)^2)/(2*gamma^2)) \n B=%5.4f, A=%5.4f, gamma=%5.6f, t_0=%5.6f,' % tuple(best_vals))
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    return None
```

**Fitting Function:**

```
def gauss2(B, A, delta, gamma, t_0):
    delta_2 = delta - t_0
    return B+A*np.exp((-(delta_2)**2)/(2*gamma**2))
```

**Fit Parameters:**

```
fitInitGuess = [1.2, 1.9, 0.25, 0.25]
fitBounds=((1.1, 0, 0, 0),(1.3, 2.5, 0.5, 0.5))
fit2(df, gauss2, fitInitGuess, fitBounds)
```

**Resulting fit:**
[image: poor gaussian fit]

**Question:**

As you can see in the plot above the fit to the gaussian that I generated is very poor. The initial guesses and bounds which I pass to my `fit2` function, and to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, seem like they should produce a better fit. I have never had this issue before, and I've had several people look over this code, perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but why is this fit not working?

Comment: Why would you attempt to fit to an analytically generated Gaussian? You can just calculate the parameters exactly, no fit necessary.

Comment: @Reinderien One would assume they have actual data for their problem but are generating an exact gaussian to fit so they can show that they're having a problem even under ideal circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable parameter is supposed to be first, not last.

```py
def gauss2(t_0, B, A, delta, gamma):
    delta_2 = delta - t_0
    return B+A*np.exp((-(delta_2)**2)/(2*gamma**2))
```

[image]

Comment: Solved. Note to others; technically the variable parameter in my example here is actually ```delta```. You may get a good fit with ```t_0``` as the first argument since it is an offset on ```delta``` but this not correct and will not, I believe, give the best fit that you can get with your data variable (ie. ```delta```) as the first argument.